# Visual Studio 2022 - Add Container Orchestrator Support - No "Docker Compose" option?

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I created a ASP.NET Core 7 WebAPI project and now I want to add docker support (with docker-compose).

I installed the latest version of Docker Desktop and Visual Studio. I followed [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2022) (and several other tutorials found online) but somehow, when trying to add Orchestrator Support, I only get the "Service Fabric" option. I would expect the "Docker Compose" option to show as well.

[image: As you can see, only "Service Fabric" option is shown.]

I installed all workloads in Visual Studio as described (Web Development, Azure Tools and .NET cross-platform development).

I tried different things:

- Executing `docker-compose version` in CMD returned the installed version, so I am assuming everything went well with installing Docker.
- I tried adding Docker support on project creation, this only resulted in not having the "Adding Orchestrator support" option at all. - see screenshot (Same behavior occurs when adding "Docker support" later on in the project)
  [image: After adding docking support I do not have the "Add Orchestrator Support" at all)] 
  Trying to add "Docker support" again does not change anything at all.
- Creating a ASP.NET Core 6 WebAPI project resulted in the same outcome.
- Creating an empty ASP.NET Core Project, as well as creating an ASP.NET Web-App project.

I'm aware that adding Docker-Compose to the project manually would be an option, but still, I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong in this case.

I'm running Windows 11, Visual Studio 2022 (17.7.6) and Docker Desktop 4.25.0 (126437).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your project is in a folder under the solution. If the project file is at or above the solution file you can't add compose support.

Comment: Thank you very much! I unticked the option "Place solution and project in the same directory" and it worked like a charm!